# How to unlock a User with Apex/Soql

Tags: apex, soql, user-admin

How to unlock a User with Apex/Soql? I don't want to use unlock User button.

Regards,
Sandeep

Answer (score 10):

You can unlock users via the [UserLogin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlogin.htm) record.

```
UserLogin someDude = [SELECT IsPasswordLocked FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId = 'jndfgl9sfdg08fg'];
someDude.IsPasswordLocked = false;
update someDude;
```

Comment: So it's been possible since API version 29 (not new to this release)?

Comment: I believe so. You can also Activate and deactivate(Salesforce Delete) users from the User record as well.

Comment: If you are doing this just using SOQL in the DEV console, and manually unchecking the IsPasswordLocked flag, then you will also want to include the ID in the SOQL.

Comment: I tried executing this exact code in the 'Execute Anonymous Window' (just replaced the **UserId** value) and received a [DML exception](https://i.imgur.com/Jm1WGvN.png). Am I doing it right? Additionally, a single User can have multiple UserLogins right?

Comment: @MH that sounds like a permission issue. Do you have this enabled for your user? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=resetting_and_expiring_passwords.htm&type=5

Comment: And for your second question, no. The docs state "Represents the settings that affect a user’s ability to log into an organization." not the actual login attempts. @MH

Comment: I'm trying this from a user account that has the standard 'System Administrator' profile, so I have the **Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users** permission, as well as object-level permission to edit the User record. I wonder why the UserLogin settings are captured in a separate object, as opposed to the same User object, if the relationship between them is 1:1.

Answer (score 4):

From the [User Documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)

> The password lockout status and the ability to reset the User
>   locked-out status is not available via the API. You must check and
>   reset the User password lockout status using the user interface.

Comment: This is possible in Salesforce 16, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> Ids = new Set<String>();  
Set<String> LockIds = new Set<String>();  
for (LoginHistory l : [SELECT UserId,LoginTime, status FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime = TODAY ORDER BY LoginTime DESC  ]){  
    if(!Ids.contains(l.userId)){  
        Ids.add(l.userId);  
        if(l.status == 'Password Lockout'){  
            LockIds.add(l.userId);  
        }  
    }  
}  
system.debug('### '+LockIds);  
for(String uId : LockIds){  
    System.resetPassword(uId, true);  
}
```

Comment: This will pick the topmost status for the user it worked like a charm for the BUG we have in winter16 for 2FA login