# Apex - send Account Unlock email

Tags: community, account, locking, passwords

Is there a way to trigger the account unlock emails via Apex?

I'm trying to setup a self-service solution where users can enter their username via a form and get the account unlock email, instead of waiting for an admin to unlock it manually.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119993) answer -

With below code you can unlock the user and can send your custom email.

```java
UserLogin someDude = [SELECT IsPasswordLocked FROM UserLogin WHERE UserId = 'jndfgl9sfdg08fg'];
someDude.IsPasswordLocked = false;
update someDude;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. While this doesn't trigger the unlock email, I could build my own process around this.